# Is it possible to have Branch.io deepview for selected social media?

Tags: ios, deep-linking, branch.io

I have successfully integrated the Branch to my app for deeplinking. Everything is working fine except for the likes of Facebook and Google plus. I know Facebook app is blocking all option to open the app from any external link.

So after a research I found the Deepview feature which is like the only possible option for Facebook. 
So my question is can I enable the deepview for Facebook,Google + etc and disable for email,SMS,Twitter which all seems to work as expected without deepview?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex from Branch here: this is possible for Facebook (and Twitter and Pinterest, though not currently for Google+ which doesn't even allow launching the App Store), but it requires manual enabling by our team on an app-by-app basis. Could you [submit a ticket for our Integrations team](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new) and we'll get you set up?